# getting error - Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

while retrieving data from sqlite getting below exception.

11-19 11:37:43.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1494): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

query is -

```
 Cursor c= db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+OpenHelper.TABLE_ACTIVITY_DETAIL+" WHERE "+OpenHelper.Activity_Date+" = '"+date+"'",null);

    if(c != null){
        if (c.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                task=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("task"));
                activityList.add(""+task); 
            }while(c.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    c.close();  
    db.close();
```

is there any solution?

Comment: what is the value of `date` variable?

Comment: its date in string format

Comment: The error comes from accessing a column. -1 is usually a return value of `getColumnIndex()` when the column didn't exist in the cursor. If you need help with that, please post more code.

Comment: @yuvaツ Can you post your full code? after fetching cursor what you doing?

Comment: @laalto & pratt i have added code. i'm getting error at select query

Comment: So your activity detail table does not have a column `task`.

Comment: It's there.. i have checked my database table

Comment: Post the `CREATE TABLE` you're using. Also if you've changed the schema in sqlite helper, you need to uninstall/clear data/increment version for the changes to be reflected in the database file - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run

Comment: @laalto : sry i was using primary key of table which is having column task. You are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly there is no such column named 'task'.
Please confirm your column name at the following line.

```
 task=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("task"));
```

Confirm your column name and you are good to go.